# pipe tailing files into custom filters accepting user input for each line

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create custom filters into which I can pipe tailing files.  The problem I'm running into is accepting user input to proceed line by line.

I onderstand that my first 'read line' is getting the input from the tailed in file...but I'm struggling with 'read /dev/tty0' grabbing a 'y or n' from the user to proceed.

The problem is my _response variable does not appear to be getting set.  Here are my couple of loops:

```
#!/bin/bash 
ECHO_CMD=/bin/echo
READ_CMD=/usr/bin/read
#_input_stream=$0
_input_file=/file.log



tail -f  ${_input_file} | {
        while IFS= read -r _line
        do
                lastline="$_line";
                echo ${_line} ;

                ${READ_CMD} -r -p "Are you sure? [y/N] " _response  </dev/tty

                ${ECHO_CMD} "_response=${_response}"
                _rtn=`echo ${_response} | grep -e y`

                #if [[ $_response =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]
                echo "_rtn= $_rtn "
                if [[ ${_rtn} = 0 ]]
                then
                        echo "Continuing"
                        continue
                else
                        echo "Ending"
                        break
                fi
        done
}

exit 1
```

Comment: What is `/usr/bin/read` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me which answer was supposed to be the 'continuing' one.  Assuming it is `y`, then try:

```
#!/bin/bash 
_input_file=/file.log
tail -f  ${_input_file} | {
        while IFS= read -r _line
        do
                lastline="$_line";
                echo ${_line} ;

                read -r -p "Are you sure? [y/N] " _response  </dev/tty
                case "$_response" in
                    [yY]*)
                        echo "Continuing"
                        ;;
                    *)
                        echo "Ending"
                        break
                        ;;
                esac
        done
}

exit 1
```

#### Notes

1. `read` and `echo` are bash builtins.  Without a clear reason otherwise, they should be used in preference to external binaries.
2. While an `if-then-else` statement could be used, the `case` statement provides an easy way to test variables against globs and execute appropriate commands.
3. Unlike `[[...]]`, the `case` statement is POSIX and therefore portable.

Comment: This is great! Worked as expected :)

Still not sure what I was doing wrong though...I understand now that case statements are the way to go but why was my _response variable not being populated?

Comment: @idontknow The code in the question sets `_response` using `/usr/bin/read`.  What is `/usr/bin/read`?  Since executables cannot alter the environment of their parent, I do not see how such a program could set  an environment variable for the script to use.

Comment: The usual `read` command works because it is a shell _builtin_ and can therefore create environment variables that the script can use.  Under `bash`, run `type read` and it should respond `read is a shell builtin`.

Comment: You folks are amazing.